# How to convert text (strings) of a div into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the following demo. How can I convert text of a div into an array?

```js
console.log($("#colors").Text().toArray());
console.log($.makeArray($("#colors").Text()));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="colors">
                Pink
                LightPink
                HotPink
                DeepPink
                PaleVioletRed
                MediumVioletRed
                LightSalmon
                Salmon
                DarkSalmon
                LightCoral
                IndianRed
                Crimson
                FireBrick
                DarkRed
                Red
    </div>
```

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive, replace `Text` with `text`.

Comment: Can be closed under the official reason: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step by step :

```js
console.log($("#colors").text());
console.log($("#colors").text().replace(/ +/g, ""));
console.log($("#colors").text().replace(/ +/g, "").replace(/^\n|\n$/g, ""));
console.log($("#colors").text().replace(/ +/g, "").replace(/^\n|\n$/g, "").split("\n"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="colors">
  Pink
  LightPink
  HotPink
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Based your current markup you can try following way:

```
var obj = $("#colors").text().trim();
var arr = obj.split("\n");

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ // This loop for remove white space.
 arr[i] = arr[i].trim();
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't turn text into an array. [`jQuery.makeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) is specifically to turn jQuery array-like objects into native arrays.

You want [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log($("#colors").text().trim().split(/\s+/));// split on white spaces
console.log($.trim($("#colors").text()).split(/\s+/));// for old browsers like IE
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="colors">
                Pink
                LightPink
                HotPink
                DeepPink
                PaleVioletRed
                MediumVioletRed
                LightSalmon
                Salmon
                DarkSalmon
                LightCoral
                IndianRed
                Crimson
                FireBrick
                DarkRed
                Red
    </div>
```